PCB chip antenna feed design and measurements
I am designing a PCB that includes a chip antenna first time. There is a feed trace that goes from the RF transmitter to the chip. this trace have to have a 50 Ω trace impedance.
Should there be a reference GND under the feed trace?
Is it good to have a completely gnd plane for the layers below the reference plane?
Should I see a flat line at 0 dB when I do not observe the S12 parameters of the trace that goes from the feed to the antenna chip?
SOURCE NXP 

At the same time, after the reference plane that ends with the feed, a neck is needed for the ceramic chip antenna. (It does not contain any reference plane at the bottom) The trace impedance will be distorted here.
Would it be a good practice to try to keep the 50 ohm characteristic impedance constant with a v-shaped geometry?
feed without reference plane image source 


If there were not a reference plane under the trace, what impedance would the trace have? Could it even be dimensioned to achieve 50Ω? || "Should I see a flat line at..." -- I'm afraid I am unable to parse this sentence, can you reword it for better clarity?

If there was no reference plane under the trace, I think the trace would create a characteristic impedance assuming the nearest gnd plane. What misled me was that I could not see a reference plane under the feed in this post (maybe it is just in top layer view mode)
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/190635/chip-antenna-pcb-layouts-and-feedline

Actually the trace inside the yellow area is a part of antenna, then It don't need to put reference ground on the back side.
Instead, need to make sure the transmission line impedance out of yellow area.
Just follow up the layout from antenna manufacturer to make sure the antenna will work correctly.
